# How to make a div fixed once it's full height has been scrolled past?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sidebar that I want to become position:fixed; and cling to the bottom of the screen but only after the entire div has been scrolled past.

The div needs to scroll like normal relative to it's parent and then become fixed when the bottom of that div meets the bottom of the browser window. I'm trying to achieve a sidebar like [this](http://www.zara.com/uk/en/sale/woman/outerwear-c436392.html) one.

I came across a piece of JS online which I've included in my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6xydp7jk/1/) but not being great with JS I'm not even sure if I'm doing the right thing & can't seem to get it to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $(".sidebar");
    var pos = s.offset().top+s.height(); //offset that you need is actually the div's top offset + it's height
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop(); //current scroll position of the window
    var windowheight = $(window).height(); //window height
    if (windowpos+windowheight>pos) s.addClass('stick'); //Currently visible part of the window > greater than div offset + div height, add class
        else s.removeClass('stick');
    });
});
```

**Update:** I need the js to detect when the entire element is in view and then make it fixed from the bottom. Or more precisely, when the bottom of the element hits the bottom of the window.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: you are definitely in the correct direction, i noticed some minor css issues in your code

Comment: Ok thanks for taking a look, would you mind explaining where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Like i said you are in the correct direction.
I made minor modification to your js, and css

[JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bsra441p/2/)

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $(".sidebar");
    var sideBarBottomY = s.offset().top+s.height();


    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowTopY = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowTopY>sideBarBottomY){
            s.addClass('stick');
        }else{
            s.removeClass('stick');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thats quite jumpy is there a way to make it smoother? Also my sidebar is padded down 200px would this cause issues?

Comment: @user2498890 jumpy as in when the sidebar sticks to the bottom, the body shifts left?

Comment: No jumpy as in the sidebar jumps to the bottom whereas I want it to cling to the bottom when the bottom of the sidebar meets the bottom of the browser. Do you see what I mean? I think its because I don't want the offset to be the top I want it to be the bottom if that makes sense?

Comment: If you look at http://www.zara.com/uk/en/sale/woman/outerwear-c436392.html you'll see what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @user2498890 that link leads me to the front page of zara. and i do not see a side menu

Comment: Ah ok well basically the sidebar that they use for main navigation is longer than the browser height so when you scroll it scrolls with the page until the bottom of the sidebar is reached (inline with bottom of browser window) at which point it becomes fixed. All the tutorials etc. i've found offset from the top is it possible to judge when something has scrolled past the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

it is something like that? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xydp7jk/17/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h = $(".header");
    var s = $(".sidebar");
    var f = $(".footer");
    var startat = h.offset().top+h.height();
    s.css({top: startat+"px",height: s.height()+"px"});
    var pos = s.offset().top+s.height(); //offset that you need is actually the div's top offset + it's height
    var endat = f.offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var endat = f.offset().top;
        var footer_height = f.height();
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop(); //current scroll position of the window
        var windowheight = $(window).height(); //window height

        if ((windowpos+windowheight)>pos && (windowpos+windowheight)<endat){
            s.css({top: "",height: ""});
            s.addClass("stick").removeClass("reston");
            s.css({bottom: ""});
        } else if((windowpos+windowheight)>endat){
            s.css({bottom: footer_height+"px"});
        }
        else {
            s.css({top: startat+"px",height: s.height()+"px"});
            s.removeClass("stick").addClass("reston");
            s.css({bottom: ""});
        }
    });
});
```

You Could add some css like animation to smooth scrolling effect sidebar.

or using directly the top position attribute and push the scrollTop and wait just before the "footer" like the "else if"

best regards

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. No basically the sidebar needs to start further down the page and when you scroll down it will come up like the main container then once the bottom of the sidebar meets the bottom of the browser it needs to become fixed. Really sorry if this doesn't make sense its quite hard to explain.